# Pivot a selection of columns from long to wide in pandas in a particular manner

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, data-manipulation

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = '''\
a,b,name,points,marks,sets
1,2,ben,22,5,13
1,2,dave,23,4,11
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
```

Given the above, which looks as:

```
   a  b  name  points  marks  sets
0  1  2   ben      22      5    13
1  1  2  dave      23      4    11
```

I would like to be able to reshape it to the following:

```py
csv= '''\
a,b,ben_points,dave_points,ben_marks,dave_marks,ben_sets,dave_sets
1,2,22,23,5,4,13,11
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
```

Which looks as:

```
   a  b  ben_points  dave_points  ben_marks  dave_marks  ben_sets  dave_sets
0  1  2          22           23          5           4        13         11
```

I'm not sure how to go about this though - here there is one column (`name`)
being spread (?) with a combination of three others.

Comment: Did you look at the pivot documentation?  If so what do you need help with? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: @user1558604 I don't see how this would be done with pivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do `unstack` then flatten the multiple index column

```
s=df.set_index(['a','b','name']).unstack('name')
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) 
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
   a  b  ben_points  dave_points  ben_marks  dave_marks  ben_sets  dave_sets
0  1  2          22           23          5           4        13         11
```

Same solution as above, with a different route :

```
 s = df.set_index(["a", "b", "name"]).unstack("name").swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)

 #flatten the columns and join with "_"
 s.columns =  ["_".join(entry) for entry in s.columns.to_flat_index()]

 #reset index, same as first solution
 s = s.reset_index()
```